# Java 9 Modules & IntelliJ: how to configure multiple modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, java-module

I am trying to create a very simple java modules project in IntelliJ with multiple modules.

Accordingly documentation in https://openjdk.org/projects/jigsaw/quick-start#multimodulecompile inside *src* directory, each module should have its own directory.

so i organized my project like this:

```
src/easytext.analysis/module-info.java
src/easytext.analysis/com/msantos/pluralsight/java9modules/easytext/analysis/World.java

src/easytext.cli/module-info.java
src/easytext.cli/com/msantos/pluralsight/java9modules/easytext/cli/Main.java
```

[image]

As you can see, IntelliJ gives an error: ***'module-info.java' already exists in the module***

Yet if i compile from the command line i have no issues:

```
javac --module-source-path src/main/java/ -d out $(find . -name '*.java')
```

Could someone explain to me why IntelliJ gives that error (taking in consideration that is a valid structure from java point of view) and how to fix it?

Thank you so much in advance

**Project Settings**
[image]

**IntelliJ with modules**

After defining the modules, the compilation works, but now adding dependencies to the modules, it reveals that modules have no access to each other. The compilation from the command-line again is working.

***Modules***

easytext.analysis module

```
module easytext.analysis {
    exports com.msantos.pluralsight.java9modules.easytext.analysis;
}
```

it exposes the package to the world

*easytext.cli module*

```
module easytext.cli {
    requires easytext.analysis;
}
```

It defines a dependency on easytext.analysis module

[image]

Yet as we can see from the picture, no access to the package. Why is that?

Comment: Go to File->Project Structure->Modules. That's where you configure modules for IntelliJ. Do you see anything wrong there?

Comment: there i added each module to the source code: easytext.analysis and easytext.cli. You can see it marked as blue in the project explorer. I believe that there is a difference between IntelliJ Modules, maven Modules and Java 9 Modules.

If i use Intellij to create the "module-info.java" (instead of mannually) it only let me create the firt file, the 2nd it grey out showing that is not possible to create a 2nd one

Comment: No, blue folders are just source directories. Modules are the folders with a blue rectangle on them. i.e. easytext-twomodules. Can you show a screenshot of the File->Project Structure->Modules dialog? I don't believe that you added two modules.

Comment: just added the Project Settings. But if i create module there, a directory in the project root will be created. Is that what we want?

Comment: As I thought, you only have one module in there. Delete the existing module,  and add two modules you want by using the"+" button and then "Import Module". Unlike the "New Module" option, "Import Module" does not create new folders. After that, the Content Roots of the two new modules, as well as their source directories, should be set to the two folders in src.

Comment: Thank you very much. That way i was able to configure the modules. The strange thing is that it looks we get an *.iml file per module, which means that now that files are part of the source code. Being a java project i was expecting that IDE could auto configure the project. too bad is not that way

Comment: Yet as we can see from the picture, after defining a java module dependency, there is no access to the package. Why is that?

Comment: It seems you are facing https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253066/src-test-allowed-to-declare-module-info.java-even-if-src-main-already-has-one, however, it's fixed. It seems you tried to create a JDK multi-module but not IDEA one. Can you share the full code in Google Drive or GitHub for us to take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is an unusual one, since you want to have multiple Java modules inside a single Maven module. This likely trips up IntelliJ, since it maps Maven modules to IntelliJ modules. It certainly doesn't help that these three uses of "module" are three different things.

If you plan to package your Maven module into a single jar later, note that the Java module system does not allow more than one module per jar file. I recommend turning your project into a [multi-module Maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html), with each Java module becoming a dedicated Maven module.